# Анонимные классы/функции и структурное программирование

Tags: java, android

Согласно азам структурного программирования программу надо разбивать на небольшие функции, которые можно повторно использовать.

В случае использования анонимного объекта/функции в текст функции вставляется чужеродный код, который нельзя повторно использовать и который разрывает поток управления. Причем часто он вообще не имеет отношения к функции, в которую вставлен. Например, тело обработчика нажатия на кнопку в OnCreate Activity.

На первый взгляд мне бросаются в глаза следующие возможные причины существования анонимных классов/функций:

1. Отсутствие в Java ссылок на функции (в версиях младше 8), из-за чего обработчики событий приходится назначать с написанием кучи лишних символов и анонимные классы как попытку это облегчить.
2. Желание максимально упростить написание кода, полностью пренебрегая при этом его читаемостью и понятностью.

Но я отдаю себе отчет в том, что я всего не знаю и могут существовать действительно веские причины для существования анонимных классов и функций.

Каковы эти причины?
В каких случаях использование этих механизмов оправдано?
Следует ли рассматривать их только как синтаксический способ обойти недостаток языка и не использовать в таких функциях больше чем один оператор?

Comment: Ссылки на методы в джаве есть!

Comment: Олексій Моренець, я поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Тот же обработчик нажатия - это паттерн обратного вызова (колбэк) смысл которого в том, чтобы производить отсроченное действие по событию. При этом действие не определено на этапе создания API (заранее не известно, какие именно действия потребуются при нажатии конкретной кнопки - это по вопросу чужеродного кода). Сам механизм основан на реализации интерфейсов в Java, который сам по себе предполагает отсутствие тела метода с последующей реализацией (на этапе создания конкретной программы) произвольного алгоритма действий.

Анонимная реализация интерфейса при этом - это вовсе не обязательное условие, а возможность, которая используется,  когда нам **не требуется повторное использование**. В случае, если код реакции на действие должен быть повторно использован в других классах или местах кода, то ничто не мешает вам сделать **полноценную реализацию интерфейса** (как имплементацией в класс, так и отдельным классом) и переиспользовать ее неограниченное число раз, как например - один обработчик кликов для нескольких кнопок.

Вы можете вообще не использовать анонимные классы (в пользу полноценной реализации), если для себя вы видите в этом какую то проблему. Сами по себе анонимные реализации - никакие не попытки обойти несуществующие недостатки, а одна из возможностей, которую вы можете использовать, а можете - нет. Не надо искать великий смысл и особые причины там, где их нет. Использование этих механизмов оправдано в любых случаях, когда вы, как программист, найдете их использование уместным в своем коде.

Comment: Callback просто реализуется через ссылку(указатель) на функцию. Достаточно объявить функцию и потом присвоить ссылку на нее.

Comment: Button1.OnClick = myButtonClick; А через реализацию интерфейса в Java приходится писать много лишнего - объявлять класс, да еще как правило объявлять в нем ссылку на родительский, чтобы обращаться к его полями и методам. Очень много синтаксического мусора вместо одной строчки кода. Анонимный класс отчасти решает проблему (меньше писать, можно обращаться к полям и методам объекта, в методе которого он создается), но создает при этом новые (см. загл.сообщ.)

Comment: То что вы пишите, похоже на wpf (и шарп вообще). Если это так, то за внешней простотой кроется большое количество кода, генерируемого компилятором без вашего участия, как раз это и есть синтетический сахар в чистом виде, а не то о чем пишите вы относительно Java, да она многословна, но прозрачна и гибка за счет этого. Вообще каждый язык и платформа - собственные правила и "играть" нужно по правилам того языка, на котором пишешь, не проецируя техники шарпа на джаву

Comment: Если вам нужно большое количество синтетического сахара, как в шарпе, при разработке на Android, то вам стоит обратить внимание на язык Kotlin, так установка слушателя на кнопку там имеет вид: `button1.setOnClickListener{// действия при клике}`, но за этой внешней простотой так же, как и шарпе,  стоит большое количество автогенерируемого кода

Comment: Не знаю, что кроется в Котлине, а в классических языках программирования присваивание указателя на функцию это простое копирование адреса. В случае указателя на метод, как в Дельфи - копирование двух адресов - адреса метода и адреса объекта. Это очень простая и эффективная операция. Это в Яве сначала не стали реализовывать возможность, создали себе проблему, а потом начали искать обходные пути и накручивать сложности. Но неужели в Java 8 указатели на функции не реализованы очевидным способом, а тоже через ... сахар?

Comment: @Eugene анонимный класс - это, по сути, и есть пара указателей...